# how can I write java path into hadoop-env.sh I am getting error writing file: permission denied error

Tags: linux, hadoop

I am installing hadoop 3.2.1 while configuring hadoop-env.sh file I couldn't able to write the java home path i am getting an error writing env.sh permission denied, and when i am trying to change the permission for home/hadoop i am getting an error as chmod: cannot access '/home/hdoop/hadoop-3.2.1': Permission denied

it would be really appreciated if any one can fix this thank youu

I couldn't able to write the java home path i am getting an error writing env.sh permission denied, and when i am trying to change the permission for home/hadoop i am getting an error as chmod: cannot access '/home/hdoop/hadoop-3.2.1': Permission denied

it would be really appreciated if any one can fix this thank youu

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME should be set in `.bashrc`, for example, or `/etc/profile`

Regarding your error, try using sudo on your chmod/chown commands